# How does one remove the lockring and sprockets from a Shimano MF-HG20 freewheel?

Tags: freewheel

Getting the freewheel off the hub is no problem; what I want to do is to get the sprockets off the freewheel.

I have tried tapping the lockring in an anti-clockwise direction with a steel punch, but it refuses to move. The markings on the smallest sprocket suggest that all the sprockets are splined.

[image: Shimano Mf-HG20 freewheel and sprockets]

Answer (score 3):

The lock ring should thread off anti clockwise. You’ll have to hold one of the sprockets with a chain whip to keep the whole body from turning. If you have a lock ring tool, that makes it easier.

Comment: Definitely use the correct proprietary tool for that. You might easily damage the ring or possibly the freewheel using some other tool.

Comment: What is the name of the lockring tool required? Or at least of this particular lockring?